# Как правильно построить запрос в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Есть SQL запрос:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Entity1 
WHERE DB1.dbo.Entity1.ExtID IN (SELECT ID FROM DB2.dbo.Entity2)
```

Подскажите, как такой запрос представить в Entity Framework? Создал два контекста: `Db1Context` и `Db2Context`. Есть метод, возвращающий записи:

```
public IQueryable<Entity1> GetEntity1()    
{
   return Db1Context.Entities1.Where( // а дальше - ступор :(
}
```

Comment: Не понял... Таблицы в разных БД?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

дабы не гонять данные между клиентом и сервером я бы необходимый запрос `sql` оформил в виде *табличной* функции которая возвращает необходимые данные:

```
Create functions dbo.GetEntities()
Returns Table
As Return(
    //здесь sql запрос с перечислением необходимых полей
);
```

получить данные можно будет например следующим образом:

```
var table = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Table1>("select * from [dbo].GetEntities()").ToList();
```

в классе `Table1` должны содержаться необходимые поля которые [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) будет *маппить*